# How can i pass an array as a parameter to a Vertica query from node.js?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sql-injection, vertica, node-postgres

I'm trying to execute sql queries against a vertica db. that works so far. but to prevent sql injection, I want to use parameterized queries. looks like vertica supports parameters as `?` (compared to postgres' `$1, $2, ...`)

so the parameters work, **BUT NOT** if the parameter is an array of values (to use in `IN (...)` conditions)

*any idea how to fix this?*

---

let's say I have a list of user ids and a name:

```
const userIds = [1, 2, 3];
const name = 'robert'
```

### postgres db (working!)

using `pg` package:

```
const pool = new pg.Pool({ /* config */ });
const client = await pool.connect();

const { rows } = client.query(`
  SELECT * FROM users WHERE first_name = $1 AND user_id = ANY($2);
`, [name, userIds]);
```

using `postgres`:

```
const sql = postgres({ /* postgres db config */ });
const rows = await sql`
  SELECT * FROM users WHERE first_name = ${name} AND user_id = ANY(${userIds});
`;
```

### vertica db (NOT working)

> only works if `userIds` is passed as a single value, not an array of 1+ values

using `vertica-nodejs`:

```
import Vertica from 'vertica-nodejs';
const { Pool } = Vertica;
const pool = new Pool({ /* vertica db config */ });

const res = await pool.query(`
  SELECT * FROM users WHERE first_name = ? AND user_id IN (?);
`, [name, userIds]);

// -> Invalid input syntax for integer: "{"1","2","3"}"
```

using `vertica`:
doesn't seem to support parameters at all, just provides a function (`quote`) to sanitize them before string interpolation.

using `pg`:

```
const pool = new pg.Pool({ /* vertica db config */ });
const client = await pool.connect();

const { rows } = client.query(`
  SELECT * FROM users WHERE first_name = ? AND user_id IN (?);
`, [name, userIds]);

// -> Invalid input syntax for integer: "{"1","2","3"}"
```

using `postgres`:
(doesn't seem to support connecting to a vertica db at all)

```
const sql = postgres({ /* vertica db config */ });
const rows = await sql`
  SELECT * FROM users;
`;

// -> Schema "pg_catalog" does not exist
```

---

I also tried those variations instead of `user_id IN (?)`:

- `user_id IN (?::int[])` -> Operator does not exist: int = array[int]
- `user_id = ANY (?)` -> Type "Int8Array1D" does not exist
- `user_id = ANY (?::int[])` -> Type "Int8Array1D" does not exist

Answer (score 1):

Try `ANY (ARRAY [$1])` .
I don't know about `node.js` or SQL injection, but in a bash shell it seems to work:

```bash
marco ~/1/Vertica/supp $ cat test.sh      
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
vsql -c "
SELECT cust_id,cust_from_dt,cust_fname,cust_lname 
FROM scd.d_customer_scd 
WHERE cust_id = ANY(ARRAY[$1]) 
ORDER BY 1,2"
marco ~/1/Vertica/supp $ ./test.sh 1,2,3
 cust_id | cust_from_dt | cust_fname | cust_lname 
---------+--------------+------------+------------
       1 | 2021-12-05   | Arthur     | Dent
       1 | 2021-12-15   | Arthur     | Dent
       1 | 2021-12-22   | Arthur     | Dent
       1 | 2021-12-29   | Arthur     | Dent
       2 | 2021-12-05   | Ford       | Prefect
       3 | 2021-11-05   | Zaphod     | Beeblebrox
       3 | 2021-12-15   | Zaphod     | Beeblebrox
       3 | 2021-12-22   | Zaphod     | Beeblebrox
       3 | 2021-12-29   | Zaphod     | Beeblebrox
(9 rows)

marco ~/1/Vertica/supp $
```

Comment: I tried `WHERE user_id = ANY(ARRAY [?])`, passing an array of integers.
result: `Could not find array type for data type canonicalintvarchar`

Comment: Note how I created the integer array in the call of the shell script: It's a list of integer literals, comma separated: `1,2,3`. No quotes, hence no "`canonicalintvarchar`"

Comment: sure, but I'm also sending it as: `client.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id IN (?);", [[1, 2, 3]])`

Comment: The square brackets in `[[1, 2, 3]]` will kill you. Can't you get rid of them?

Comment: You can't pass any data as JSON literals, you'll need to pass the data as SQL literals. If they need to be strings it's single, not double, quotes. Double quotes, in SQL, as they will be interpreted here, enclose identifiers, e.g column names, not string literals

Comment: first of all, the double quotes are just for node/js. again, the query works fine if I just do this: `client.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = ?;", [1])` the 2nd parameter of the `query` function is the array of parameters... so when I want to send an array as a parameter, it's going to be an array inside an array. maybe this way it's easier to see: `client.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE first_name = $1 AND user_id = ANY($2);", ["robert", [1, 2, 3]]);`

Comment: anyway, i do appreciate you trying to help :)